# AWS Lambda のテストで KeyError (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, python3, aws-lambda

lambdaとpythonの初学者です。
以下のコードを実行しました。

```
import boto3
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

def handler(event, context):
    #必要な定数を定義
    BUCKET_NAME = event['bucket_name']
    BUCKET_KEY = event['bucket_key']
    UPLOAD_BUCKET_KEY = 'b.json'
    
    #a.json読込
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, key=BUCKET_KEY)
    data = json.loads(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(f'{BUCKET_KEY}の内容: {data}')
    
    #b.sjonのアップロード
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).Object(UPLOAD_BUCKET_KEY)
    data = OrderedDict(file_name=UPLOAD_BUCKET_KEY, author=data['author'], age=(data['age']+1))
    
    res = obj.put(Body=json.dumps(data))
    if res['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
        print(f'[SUCCESS] upload {UPLOAD_BUCKET_KEY}')
```

AWSのLambdaでテストを実行しました。
その結果、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
  "errorMessage": "'bucket_name'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "752f59f8-f95a-4903-8412-60334115be69",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 7, in handler\n    BUCKET_NAME = event['bucket_name']\n"
  ]
}
```

lambdaのテストイベントは以下のように記述しました。

```
{
  "BUCKET_NAME": "bucket_name",
  "BUCKET_KEY": "bucket_key"
}
```

ハンドラはmain.handlerと設定しこのコードの関数を呼ぶように指定しています。
エラーの原因が分からずに困っています。

AWSのlambdaのテストイベントで修正をしました。

```
{
  "bucket_name": "lambda-test-keein",
  "bucket_key": "a.json"
}
```

再度、テストを実行したところエラーが変わりました。

```
VersionId, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, RequestPayer, PartNumber, ExpectedBucketOwner",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "requestId": "ed79a6d9-2510-42fe-8105-d43732124bb2",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 13, in handler\n    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, key=BUCKET_KEY)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 677, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 725, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 337, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
```

}

Answer (score 3):

あまりPythonで書いたことはありませんが、

```
{
  "BUCKET_NAME": "bucket_name",
  "BUCKET_KEY": "bucket_key"
}
```

辞書のkeyは、"BUCKET_NAME", "BUCKET_KEY"なので、valueを参照するなら、

```py
    #必要な定数を定義
    BUCKET_NAME = event['BUCKET_NAME']
    BUCKET_KEY = event['BUCKET_KEY']
```

ではないでしょうか？

[Python の Lambda 関数ハンドラー - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決しました。
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, key=BUCKET_KEY)
を
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=BUCKET_KEY)
にしてAWS上のファイルを削除してLambdaに再度アップロードし実行したところ正常に動作しました。